# Javascript pop up window script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript code for opening a popup window. It has to pass 2 parameters to the php script.

Here is the snippet of the code:

`window.open('commercial_files/ttform.php?tender_id='+result["tender_id"]&id='+result["id"],
    'quotation','scrollbars=yes','menubar=no','status=no','width=800,height=600');`

There is some problem with comma and apostrophe near "?". `tender_id='+result["tender_id"]&id='+result["id"]`.

Comment: window.open('commercial_files/ttform.php?tender_id='+result["tender_id"]+'&id='+result["id"],
'quotation','scrollbars=yes','menubar=no','status=no','width=800,height=600');

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have missed `'` for `&id`
in

```
tender_id='+result["tender_id"]&id='+result["id"],
```

---------------------------------------------^^^----------------------

it should be like

```
window.open('commercial_files/ttform.php?tender_id='+result[‌​"tender_id"]+'&id='+‌​result["id"], 'quotation','scrollbars=yes','menubar=no','status=no','width‌​=800,height=600');
```